# Jupyter notebook - suppress output from tsfresh

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to suppress the output of the "extract_features" and "select_features" classes from the tsfresh library, because the output slows down my jupyter notebooks. Unfortunately, the classes don't contain any arguments for suppressing all output.

I tried to use %%capture but that just suppresses notebook output, but not the output from the classes and I didn't manage to find print statements within the classes in the .py files associated with the library.

[image: Here is a screenshot depicting notebook output which can't be suppressed using %%capture]

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is having a similar issue, here is the solution that worked for me:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger() 
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those messages are generated from the `logging` module.  You can try to redirect them to a file by importing `logging` and setting an output path.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='tslog.log')
```

Comment: Thank you James. While your exact suggestion didn't help, it lead me down the direct path.